# Contracts - is events / logging going to be added?

Tags: contract, logging

The Ethereum Solidity contract system has a feature for adding events (logging) which can be subscribed via the RPC and also searched for (as the events are stored on the blockchain).

Is there going to be something similar added to the Tezos contract system in the future?

I feel this is very a powerful feature for verification and also debugging.

Answer (score 1):

[Contract events](https://tezos.gitlab.io/alpha/event.html) are introduced in Protocol Kathmandu. You may now emit events from contracts with reasonable cost.

Answer (score 0):

There have not been any protocol upgrades (as of Edo) that introduce contract event logging, but there is a [proposal draft](https://gitlab.com/tzip/tzip/-/merge_requests/121/diffs).